# text box assign to variable type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if someone can help identify the problem in the following code. I am just trying to get the value of a text box if text box is not empty or a 0 and assign it to a variable. Error i am getting -> Type mismatch

Thank you all in advance.

```
Private Sub Util_NumberQC_Change()


Dim Util_Get As String

If Not Util_NumberQC.Value = 0 Or "" Then

Util_Get = Sheet3.Util_NumberQC.Value

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
If Not Util_NumberQC.Value = 0 Or Util_NumberQC.Value = "" Then
```